# Persistent threads vs device-side-enqueue/nested-parallelism

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

Are there still advantages to using persistent threads in GPGPU vs using device-side-enqueue/nested-parallelism if they can be applied?

I have read some older papers where persistent threads were needed on older hardware to get best performance and I am not sure if using device-side-enqueue/nested-parallelism has made that technique irrelevant?

I suppose in cases where child tasks are totally independent after launch from their parents persistent threads may still be worthwhile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persistent threads as a programming methodology will probably continue to be of interest for some time.  Persistent threads may offer several advantages over nested parallelism.  Here are 2:

1. Elimination of launch latency:  Although it is small (perhaps as low as a few microseconds), at least in the case of CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (CDP) there is a launch latency associated with both host kernel launches and child kernel launches.  For extremely low-latency demands (e.g. network packet processing) a producer/consumer work queue model with persistent threads can offer lower latency and faster turnaround than any mechanism that involves a launch associated with the receipt of new work.
2. Optimization for memory usage: A novel new use case for persistent threads is to avoid the load/store patterns associated with kernel launches.  A good description of an example is [here](https://svail.github.io/persistent_rnns/).  The basic idea is that for repeated processing of a similar workload, we can carefully optimize usage of on-chip data storage (including shared memory but also in particular the use of GPU register space) so as to avoid having to load the data/parameters at kernel launch e.g. from global memory and then (perhaps) store the updated parameters back out to global memory at the conclusion of a kernel.  This can have dramatic processing benefits for particular workloads where there is a large amount of carried parameter usage, and the parameter space can be made to "fit" on-chip.  As newer GPUs have more and more on-chip register storage space, this will probably continue to be of interest for even larger workloads.

It's quite likely that there are other specific use cases also, where a persistent threads approach offers clear advantages over a launch-on-work approach.  These are just two examples.

In short, persistent kernels is not a general strategy for replacement of other types of GPU processing paradigms, but in specific cases it can provide benefits over methods that launch kernels repeatedly.  Therefore some interest in persistent kernels will probably continue for some time.

Comment: This is the most informative answer I have ever had to a question on stackoverflow!  Also strangely the fastest actually answered!  The point and example on it helping to optimise the caching of data was very helpful.  Do you perhaps know if the situation changes at all with nVidia's Pascal CUDA 8 multiblock coop groups that can somehow preserve register/shared-mem state between executions?  Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not aware of Pascal/CUDA 8 being able to preserve the state of either on-chip registers or shared memory from one kernel launch to the next.  No such facility exists that I am aware of.  Can you cite a reference for that claim?

Comment: From random googling I found a mention of it towards the end of this document: https://asc.llnl.gov/DOE-COE-Mtg-2016/talks/1-10_NVIDIA.pdf.  But I am not clear how exactly that works.

Comment: That presentation affirms that any multi-kernel approach will lose state (registers, shared mem) on slides 23 and 25.  The multi-block cooperative approach is a way to get around this, but it does not involve multiple kernel launches nor does it "preserve ... state between executions" (of kernels).    The "phases of execution" there are conceptual, and the idea is that they no longer need to be broken up by explicit kernel launches. Also note that multiblock cooperative groups is a preview; it's not exposed in CUDA 8  (AFAIK) and it is in a section of the presentation entitled "Beyond CUDA 8"

Comment: I don't quite understand how that would work - does it mean the same kernel reruns with the same threadblock multiple times?  So sort of a persistent thread block = multiblock coop, and that the kernel would be written like a megakernel type of thing to identify what 'stage' it is at?  (I skimmed over the Beyond CUDA 8 it seems so thanks for that!)

Comment: Currently, CUDA does not offer a global sync or any multi-block sync, other than the kernel launch.  Therefore, work that requires a global sync would have to be broken up into separate kernels, which has implications for on-chip state.  The new mechanism is introducing a new multi-block sync capability (essentially a variable-scope sync), which might obviate the need to break work into separate kernels.  Beyond that, if you want a detailed discussion, I suggest you ask a new question.  And I'm not suggesting I would attempt to answer that question. This mechanism hasn't been documented AFAIK.

Comment: That's fine, thank you for taking the time to explain, as it's been most helpful to my understanding of this all.